# MySQL yearweek function space

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the function `yearweek` in a select query.

My question = when the date = 2017-02-13 || yearweek = 201707. How can I get a space between `2017 07`

Comment: in your output of the query? Or where do you want your space?

Comment: i want it to pass it along to the view with a space between it "SELECT actief,userid, YEARWEEK(datum) this is the query well a small piece of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
CREATE TABLE tu(datum DATE);
INSERT INTO tu(datum) VALUES ('2017-02-13');

SELECT  datum, DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%X %V'), YEARWEEK(datum)
FROM tu;
```

Output:

```
13.02.2017 00:00:00       2017 07          201707
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/MZMUA22052)**

> **%X**        Year for the week where **Sunday** is the first day of the week. Used with %V
>
> **%x**    Year for the week where **Monday** is the first day of the week. Used with %V

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: need 1 more rep